# How to implement Numpy where index in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following operations which uses `numpy.where`:

```
    mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.int32)
    index = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
    mat[np.where(index>0)] = 100
    print(mat)
```

How to implement the equivalent in TensorFlow?

```
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.int32)
index = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
tf_mat = tf.constant(mat)
tf_index = tf.constant(index)
indi = tf.where(tf_index>0)
tf_mat[indi] = -1   <===== not allowed
```

Comment: `np.where()` is unneeded here: `mat[index > 0] = 100`

Comment: anyway, how to meet the same intention in tensorflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to create a new tensor with some replaced elements, and not update a variable, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.int32)
index = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
tf_mat = tf.constant(mat)
tf_index = tf.constant(index)
tf_mat = tf.where(tf_index > 0, -tf.ones_like(tf_mat), tf_mat)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_mat))
```

Output:

```
[[-1  2  3]
 [ 4 -1  6]
 [ 7  8 -1]]
```

Comment: it is not what I want!

Comment: @Roby Umh, can you clarify then what exactly do you want? Or what about the answer does not meet your needs?

Comment: @Roby Whoops sorry, just realised I copied the wrong matrix at the output (the code is still fine...), fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You can get indexes by `tf.where`, then you can either run the index, or use `tf.gather` to collect data from the origin array, or use `tf.scatter_update` to update origin data, `tf.scatter_nd_update` for multi-dimension update.

```
mat = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=tf.int32)
index = tf.Variable([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
idx = tf.where(index>0)
tf.scatter_nd_update(mat, idx, /*values you want*/)
```

note that update values should be the same first dimension size with idx.

see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python

Comment: `idx` used in `scatter_update` is 1D,  `tf.where` return not work here!

Comment: if you want to use more than 1D update, use `tf.scatter_nd_update` instead of `tf.scatter_update`

Comment: yes, `tf.scatter_nd_update` works,  it is an alternative method to  `tf.where()` as @jdehesa suggested.  Thank you though.